# FirebaseUI for User Authentication and Sign In, not showing sign in option in display

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin, firebaseui

I am trying to make an android application in which user can sign in using google account with email and password through Firebase user authentication and Firebase UI. I have tried with the following java code, that is written. I would like to admit that curly brackets might have been misplaced in writing the code here but in android studio, there was no such issue with regard to the curly brackets. I have not written activity_main.xml code since I thought that FirebaseUI would add the sign in flow itself.
All the images which I though would be helpful in guiding, are attached.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
       package com.example.findaplayer;

       import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
       import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.widget.Toast;

       import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
       import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
       import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

       import java.util.Arrays;
       import java.util.List;

       public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

           private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
           private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener ;

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

              mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

              mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {

              @Override
              public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                  FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                  if (user != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome to findaplayer app", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   } else {

                      // Choose authentication providers
                      List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                           new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                           new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
                           new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
                           new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build(),
                           new AuthUI.IdpConfig.TwitterBuilder().build());

                   // Create and launch sign-in intent
                      startActivityForResult(
                                 AuthUI.getInstance()
                                         .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                         .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                                         .build(),
                                            1) ;


                   }
               }

           };
           }

          }
```

I am not getting any error in the event log as shown in the attached screenshot named, event log. The problem I am facing is that when this app is run on the emulator it is not showing sign in option, instead it's just showing hello world while I think its display should include sign in option because Firebase UI library is being used for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You have an `mAuthStateListener` listener declared, but you never told the Firebase Auth SDK to use it with [addAuthStateListener()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#addAuthStateListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)):

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
```